# Support in C# Bingmaps Project

Tags: c#

My C# Bingmaps project is working on the desktop platform, in my bingmaps project I want to show the data from the datagrid on the MyWebBrowser object, but it shows 1, the number of incoming coordinates from the datagrid is 10, but on the MyWebBrowser it shows 1. I don't know exactly what my mistake is. My project has 4 columns in total as X, Y, ConfidenceStatus, Building Name, from which the data is drawn from the map table. I am giving the codes below now. I have given all the details in order to be healthy, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Hi, it would help if you post the relevant code as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.